# Azure media service vs regular file storage for processing videos

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

What should I use from Azure for an application where I am uploading videos and I want to process videos to obtain information with my own worker roles but I dont want to stream the videos. Should I use Media service or regular blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Devsined, per my experience, my suggestion is that uploading & processing videos to & from blob storage is the better choice to obtain information. Even I think, if having Azure App services consideration, you can upload videos into queue storage first, then to store into blob storage, and using webjobs to handle the vedio from queue and record the obtained inforamtion to Azure Database.
Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes I am leaning towards use a only a blob and doing the processing later but I just want to know if the media services offers something else better. At the end the media services uses blob storage and then it encodes and allows stream later. Thus, I think I will implement the solution similar to what you are describing since I dont see and nobody give me an argument that point to th media services.